# How do I change icons for builtin actions in ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor4.x

How do I change the icons for builtin actions such as subscript, superscript bold and italic?

The documentation say that I have to place the icons in the images folder in my skin, but how do I know what the image should be called?

Also, ckeditor compiles the default images into one huge file, so do I need to rebuild that icon file(how?) after placing an icon.

I am using Ckeditor 4.

Answer (score 0):

All skin icons must be included inside the icons folder in the skin folder. The icons file name must match the name of the icon files available in the icons folder of the plugins.

If you want the source version of your skin to overload icons properly, you must inform CKEditor about the presence of your custom icons. This is optional, but if not done your icons will be visible in the release version of your skin only. Check the skin.js file in the Moono skin for an example.

Try clearing the cache as well.

Comment: But my CKEditor don't have a plugin folder for the build in options such as bold.

Answer (score 0):

I've just downloaded CKEditor v4.5.7 basic edition and there is a "plugins" folder by default.

Are you sure about the version used ?

After edit :

Icons are defined in the file skins/moono/editor.css and for example for Bold look after class .cke_button__bold_icon - erverything can be changed there.

In order not to edit standard files, I suggest you to create a new skin : duplicate moono folder and rename as you like and in your config.js add

```
config.skin = 'skin-name';
```

Comment: Yes there is a plugin folder. But it don't contain all the basic plugins such as bold, subscription and so on